# How to sort hashtable/enumeration based on original input

Tags: java, hashtable, enumeration

I created a dictionary to output the keys of a hashtable.

```
import java.util.Dictionary;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.Hashtable;

public class Foo {
    public static void main (String [] args) {
         Dictionary<String, String> dict = new Hashtable<String, String>();
         dict.put("Emma", "Watson");
         dict.put("Tom", "Hanks");
         dict.put("Keanu", "Reeves");
    
         Enumeration<String> emu = dict.keys();
    
         while (emu.hasMoreElements()) {
              System.out.println(emu.nextElement());
         }
    }
}
```

Output :

```
Keanu
Emma
Tom
```

I want the output to be listed as the original order I put it in (Emma, Tom, Keanu) but it prints out this random order thats not even alphebetical. Please help me understand how and why this happens, and how to fix the problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be using `LinkedHashMap<>`, which combines a hash map for quick access but also keeps the elements ordered by their insertion order.  For example

```
Map<String,String> dict = new LinkedHashMap<>();
dict.put("Emma", "Watson");
dict.put("Tom", "Hanks");
dict.put("Keanu", "Reeves");

for (String s : dict.keySet())
    System.out.println(s);
```

This will output the keys in the order in which they were inserted into the map.

BTW, `Dictionary`, `Hashtable` and related classes are very old and are superseded by `Map` and its implementations.

Answer (score 1):

Read about hashCode and equals. Hash collections are almost always contains elements in random orders (maybe without something like LinkedHashSet or LinkedHashMap which keep enter order but this is something else). They are faster to get elements from any position. In your problem I think you can wrap your Strings into new class like Name and use Comparator or Comparable interfaces to sort them. Or just change Dictionary to HashTable and get EntrySet:

```
public static void main (String [] args) {
    Hashtable<String, String> dict = new Hashtable<>();
    dict.put("Emma", "Watson");
    dict.put("Tom", "Hanks");
    dict.put("Keanu", "Reeves");

    for (Map.Entry<String, String> s : dict.entrySet()) {
        //ordered by entry
        System.out.println(s.getKey());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put it in another hashtable with Hashtable <Int, String>, where int is the order and string is the key. then put the hashtable in the bigger hashtable so that the hashtable is <<int, String>, String>

Comment: Isn't there a much simpler way to sort it? That seems like extra unnecessary work

Comment: This is a terrible idea.   `LinkedHashMap` is the way  to go as it preserves insertion order..

Comment: Not very cool, you should verify it before post it as an answer